# PrettyPhoto location makes my Facebook likes to disappear

Tags: facebook

I'm having some problems, I'm reorganising my website and I'm creating a different folder structure than I have now. I succesfuly move everything but whenever I point this script:

- jquery.prettyPhoto.js

in the meta tags to the new location all my facebook likes from my gallery are gone, everything else is working, I can click like again but uhm, if I point in the header to the old location of the script all the likes re-appear.
If you're wondering the Likes I receive are created when the users open in PrettyPhoto an image from my gallery.
Can you please help me fix my problem? I'm moving the resources under the same domain name, just a different folder.
Thank you very much Sir.

Answer (score 0):

Is pretty photo changing the url? Try using this option: **deeplinking: false**

Comment: No, that's not my problem, that's for #!prett.. after the link, my problem is that I have http://domain.com/cpanel/theme/version/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js and I want to re-organise my folder structures like: http://domain.com/engine/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js and whenever I point to the new .js structure in the <head> all my likes from the photos that open in PrettyPhoto they are gone, but when I link back to the old .js structure the likes are coming back.